# Produce an ordered HTML list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to display my JS array as an ordered list as you would do with html element . Suppose an array of strings is passe such as: `pets(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'])`, I want to return:

1: cat
2: dog
3: mouse

However there is a specific way I'd like to get this done. Take a look below:

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  return index + ':' + element;
}

var pets = function(array){
  if (array.length <= 0) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return array.forEach(logArrayElements);
  }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get 'undefined'. Why is that?

This is not homework, just self learning. Also check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emporio/ohfrhfs5/14/

Comment: I don't understand your question; I think you're using some terms whose meanings you don't understand ("sort", "ordered list") . . .

Comment: What's wrong with the sort function?

Comment: Do you realize you just asked for the array to be returned unchanged? Check your question, the input is the same as the output.  Try to think more carefully about your questions in the future.

Comment: The sort function doesn't add the numbers before like an ordered list does

Comment: Are you trying to create an actual `<ol>` ordered list, or just a text list?

Comment: an ordered list but without jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `forEach`, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
return array.map(logArrayElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the built-in [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. So you would be having:

```
function pets(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP actually wants to "sort" the array, as we understand that term. Note that in his/her example, the array is already sorted to begin with.